# Will Duplo trains fit onto a regular 6 stud LEGO track?

Tags: piece-information, trains, compatibility, duplo

There's a [thread](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/1534/9767) here establishing that regular LEGO trains arguably fit onto Duplo track, but have trouble with underbelly clearance.

What about the opposite? Will a Duplo train fit onto six-stud gauge [LEGO track](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/2885/9767)?

To be clear, I am excluding control and power functions - I'm asking if a Duplo train will fit on the tracks and roll freely without derailing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For this experiment we're using the wheeled *Duplo* push and go motor block and red cabin from *[Set #10874](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=10874-1)*.

The wheel width of the motor is the same width as a non motor base.

[image] [image] [image]

So, for this train to stay on the six stud track, the wheels need to sit either on the inside of the tracks or the outside of the tracks.

As the last picture shows, the wheels float on top of the tracks, which allows the train to slip off.

If this red train represents the standard width of most *Duplo* trains, then we can conclude that a *Duplo* train will not fit on a six-stud gauge *LEGO* track and roll freely without derailing.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

***UPDATE***: Just getting our digital groove on.
[image]

[image]

Comment: It is wonderful to see duct tape and a metal ruler being useful for LEGO's.

Comment: This is an awesome and thorough answer.